# Hibernate Syntax for using both fetch/select

Tags: hibernate, select, fetch

I am having some trouble mixing and matching fetches and selects using hibernate.
Basically, I am listing a bunch of users in a user table which also contains a "createdBy" column which references the user table by id
Ex:

```
id  | name | foo | createdBy
----------------------------
1     abc    zzz   2
2     def    zzz   2
```

So, In the example above I would want an instance of the "def" user to be returned for "abc"'s createdBy column

So, without the createdBy, my query looks like:

```
from User u inner join fetch e.foo as foo inner join fetch foo.bar as bar
```

How would I insert the

```
"select User u2 from User where u2.id=u.createdBy"
```

into the previous query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `createdBy` is  mapped in the `User` entity as lazy `ManyToOne` you would include it in your query in the exact same fashion as your other joins:

```
from User u
  join fetch u.foo as foo
  join fetch foo.bar as bar
  join fetch u.createdBy
```

If it's not mapped as `ManyToOne` (why not?) and instead only its ID is mapped, you'll have to use a cross join *AND* you will either have to transform query result (via custom constructor or `ResultTransformer` implementation) or consume them as `List<Object[]>` as that's what they'll be:

```
select u, u2
  from User u, User u2
    join fetch u.foo as foo
    join fetch foo.bar as bar
 where u.createdBy = u2.id
```

Needless to say, the first option (mapping `createdBy` as `ManyToOne`) is much more straightforward.